# Store Gujrati language in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I Want to store gujrati charecter in database but it's show junk character in database here is my table structure
[image]

show me output like this

[image]

i have tried **utf8_general_ci** And **utf8mb4_general_ci** Collation But It's Not Working

Comment: This answer is pretty complete, but it's on a sister site, not Stack Overflow: https://superuser.com/questions/741864/how-to-display-text-in-utf8-from-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: I was able to test and I created a test table and stored the string "ગુજરાતી" and displayed it correctly. The table was defined with utf8 character set and utf8_general_ci collation. But I was using the MySQL command-line client, not phpmyadmin. So I guess it's a PHP configuration issue.